# Save user data in localstorage, anyone can change it

Tags: angularjs

I have code to check, is user authenticated

```
return !!$localStorage.user;
```

In chrome developer tool, I am able to change the value, which updated in local storage and return the changed value in any call.

Other Scenario: If store into the service variable, after refreshing the page it lost.

So the question is, how and where to save the user detail with role in angularjs

Comment: Typically a cookie is used that contains a unique `id` value which is usually a pointer to a server side session mechanism. I wouldn't advise keeping session data in `localStorage` because default browser settings usually don't clear this on shutdown. (i.e. the session would persist across browser launches)

Comment: Sure you might be able to change the localStorage data, but requests to the server still should be passing a layer of authentication to ensure its within the users privilege scope..

Comment: Yeah, encrypt the data and put it in a session cookie. Decrypt on the server side to get any necessary values back. Tamper evident client-side data storage unless your encryption key is leaked or cracked.

Comment: Zack: what do you mean by 'within the users privilege scope'?